# How do I make 2 divs float, next to one another, inside a div inside a li

Tags: css-float, html-lists, html

This is the coding I am using.  i have been messing with it for hours. Below is the CSS I am using

```
<ul class="slider">
  <li style="display: block;">
    <a href="#" style="clear:both;>
       <div class="slider_blog" style="width: 680px; height: 300px; display: block; clear: both; float: left;">
         <div class="slider_blog_img">
           <img src="#" alt="#">
         </div>
         <div class="slider_blog_text" style="float:left;">
           <h2>This is A Title</h2>
           <p></p>
           <p>words</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS I am using

```
.slider li {
  display: none, block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0px;
  width:680px;
  height:300px;
}

.slider li:after{
  clear:both;
}

.slider_blog{
  border: 1px solid #F0E; clear: both; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

.slider_blog a{
 text-decoration: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

.slider_blog_img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

.slider_blog img{
  width: 200px; height: 200px; margin:50px; border: none; display:block;
}

.slider_blog_text{
 width: 280px; padding: 50px 20px 50px 0px; border:none;
}

.slider_blog_text h2{
 text-align:center; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:red; 
}

.slider_blog_text p{
  text-align:justify; font-size:14px; color:green;
}
```

I know their is some inline stuff added with CSS, but this is copied from Firebug when I "though" i was making progress.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `<a>` tag is missing an ending style quote. Try fixing that first and then explain the problem better. Also, try adding a `float:left` to the `.slider_blog_img` class and removing the set width and height for now.

Comment: thanks for the help it ended up being a margin that was being created on a p tag from some other element in Word Press that was screwing it all up.

Answer (score 0):

well do as instructed by `TJohnW` i.e

provide end quotes

```
<a href="#" style="clear:both;">
```

and use this

```
.slider_blog_img {
    float: left;
}
```

**[output](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/h3wFX/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I got it fixed, but the issue isn't the coding it is wordpress.  It is randomly adding <p></p> tag in the middle of something and I can't figure out why that is.